# plot multiple parametric curves on the same axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I want to draw  two parametric curves and their images, in the following way: the first one to be in blue, and the second one to be in red:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[trig format=rad,scale=3,
  declare function={%
  gammarx(\r,\t)=(t);
   gammary(\r,\t)=(r);}]
 \foreach \r in {1,2,3,4,5}
 {\draw plot[smooth,samples=150, variable=\t,domain=-10:10] 
   ({gammarx(\r,\t)},{gammary(\r,\t)});}
\end{tikzpicture}
 
\begin{tikzpicture}[trig format=rad,scale=3,
  declare function={%
  gammarx(\r,\t)=(r);
   gammary(\r,\t)=(t);}]
 \foreach \r in {-1,-2,-3,1,2,3}
 {\draw plot[smooth,samples=150, variable=\t,domain=0:10] 
   ({gammarx(\r,\t)},{gammary(\r,\t)});}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And then draw their images  under a function f lie on the same axis as well. Where f is like the following

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[trig format=rad,scale=3,
  declare function={%
  gammarx(\r,\t)=(\t*\t*(\r*\r+1)-1)/%
    (\t*\t*(\r*\r+1)+2*\r*\t+1);
   gammary(\r,\t)=(-2*\t)/(\t*\t*(\r*\r+1)+2*\r*\t+1);}]
 \foreach \r in {1,2,3,4,10}
 {\draw plot[smooth,samples=150, variable=\t,domain=0:10] 
   ({gammarx(\r,\t)},{gammary(\r,\t)});}
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}[trig format=rad,scale=3,
  declare function={%
  gammarx(\r,\t)=(\t*\t*(\r*\r+1)-1)/%
    (\t*\t*(\r*\r+1)+2*\r*\t+1);
   gammary(\r,\t)=(2*\t)/(\t*\t*(\r*\r+1)+2*\r*\t+1);}]
 \foreach \r in {1,2,3,4,10}
 {\draw plot[smooth,samples=150, variable=\t,domain=0:10] 
   ({gammarx(\r,\t)},{gammary(\r,\t)});}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

i.e, like the picture [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the parametric plots are related by swapping the roles of x and y, you may just swap the entries in the argument of the plot. Otherwise I only put things in scopes and changes some scales and domains a bit to avoid the plot growing too big.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[trig format=rad]
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=L,scale=0.5,declare function={%
  gammarx(\r,\t)=(\t);
   gammary(\r,\t)=(\r);}]
 \foreach \r in {1,2,3,4,5}
 {\draw[red] plot[smooth,samples=2, variable=\t,domain=-5:5] 
   ({gammarx(\r,\t)},{gammary(\r,\t)});}
 \foreach \r in {-1,-2,-3,1,2,3}
 {\draw[blue] plot[smooth,samples=2, variable=\t,domain=0:6] 
   ({gammary(\r,\t)},{gammarx(\r,\t)});}
\end{scope}
%
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=R,xshift=7cm,yshift=2cm,scale=3,
  declare function={%
  gammarx(\r,\t)=(\t*\t*(\r*\r+1)-1)/%
    (\t*\t*(\r*\r+1)+2*\r*\t+1);
   gammary(\r,\t)=(-2*\t)/(\t*\t*(\r*\r+1)+2*\r*\t+1);}]
 \foreach \r in {1,2,3,4,10}
 {\draw[red] plot[smooth,samples=151, variable=\t,domain=0:10] 
   ({gammarx(\r,\t)},{gammary(\r,\t)});}
 \foreach \r in {1,2,3,4,10}
 {\draw[blue] plot[smooth,samples=151, variable=\t,domain=0:10] 
   ({gammary(\r,\t)},{gammarx(\r,\t)});}
\end{scope}
%
\draw[-{Stealth[bend]},semithick] (L.east) to[bend right,edge label={$f$}] (L-|R.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to add axis lines and so on, I recommend using `pgfplots`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{trig format plots=rad,width=6.5cm,axis lines=middle,
    xlabel={$x$},ylabel={$y$}}
\begin{axis}[name=L,declare function={%
  gammarx(\r,\t)=(\t);
   gammary(\r,\t)=(\r);}]
 \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,2,3,4,5}
 {\addplot[red,smooth,samples=2, variable=\t,domain=-5:5] 
   ({gammarx(#1,\t)},{gammary(#1,\t)});}
 \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-1,-2,-3,1,2,3}
 {\addplot[blue,smooth,samples=2, variable=\t,domain=0:6] 
   ({gammary(#1,\t)},{gammarx(#1,\t)});}
\end{axis}
%
\begin{axis}[name=R,xshift=7cm,
  declare function={%
  gammarx(\r,\t)=(\t*\t*(\r*\r+1)-1)/%
    (\t*\t*(\r*\r+1)+2*\r*\t+1);
   gammary(\r,\t)=(-2*\t)/(\t*\t*(\r*\r+1)+2*\r*\t+1);}]
 \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,2,3,4,10}
 {\addplot[red,smooth,samples=151, variable=\t,domain=0:10] 
   ({gammarx(#1,\t)},{gammary(#1,\t)});}
 \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,2,3,4,10}
 {\addplot[blue,smooth,samples=151, variable=\t,domain=0:10] 
   ({gammary(#1,\t)},{gammarx(#1,\t)});}
\end{axis}
%
\draw[-{Stealth[bend]},semithick] (L.east) to[bend left,edge label={$f$}] (L-|R.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Can I add the x,and y-axes on both figures?

Comment: @A.Rahman In this case I recommend switching to `pgfplots`, see the second part of the updated answer.